# Does SDL Tridion CMS authenticate user’s credentials every time a user does an activity on the CME?

Tags: tridion

It’s a plain vanilla SDL Tridion install where users are added in the CMS CME.

1. If user successfully log-in to the SDL Tridion CME (No LDAP-AD sync is used means MMC console has no LDAP-AD stuff).
2. Now user goes on doing his/her business edit/create of content page or navigation stuff around in CME.
3. Does Tridion authenticate every time user does such activity? Is this  authentication done against the LDAP-AD or some sort of cache (if there is one?)
4. Long long time back someone from advised me there is a config in Tridion where you can turn it On or OFF to authenticate for each/every activity user does after successful login.... (am not able to recall the clarity of the conversation).

Comment: Vinod, can we convince you to commit to the proposal for a separate Tridion A&Q site, follow this link http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2 and click the "Commit" button to be notified when the site is created.

Answer (score 2):

I believe IIS will indeed re-authenticate every request.

If you use something like Fiddler (which I strongly recommend) you will see that every request to a URL comes back first as an HTTP 401, then is sent back to the server with the correct credentials.

So, yes, every request must be authenticated. If you disable a user account while that user is working in Tridion, he will start getting "access denied" errors half way through their session.

Comment: NTLM/Kerberos are connection-oriented authentication schemes, so they will authenticate every new connection (not every request). Typically this means you will see a bunch of new authentications when you just get started, but after that only when a new connection is opened (e.g. when a popup opens). If you're using Fiddler, be sure to set it to re-use connections, or you will end up authentication for every request (turning every simple HTTP GET into three requests).

Comment: The question is hinting at the old experimental setting that would cause TDSEs to be cached. This caching was server-side, and would not have changed the "authentication" of the user (i.e. establishing the identity) so techniques with Fiddler would still show this behaviour. On the server, however, the user's access token would not need to be rebuilt each time. The only time I recall this was used "in anger" was for a customer who had thousands of LDAP mappings (which was, and remains, a very bad idea).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Tridion will authenticate you every time. In other words, every time you make a web request, a new TDSE or Session will be created. This can be far more often than you might think. I don't know the details for SDL Tridion 2011, but back in the R5 days, I recall that it took 6 authentications to load your starting view of the GUI.

It's quite likely that authentications against an LDAP server might be cached. The old ISAPI filter did this, however I don't recall the authorization lookups being cached. There was never a solid requirement to support exotic or "heavy" LDAP integrations.

There used to be a setting that would make the GUI cache the TDSE, but this was only ever an internal-use experimental feature. I wouldn't recommend trying to use it, and it's very clear that this configuration isn't supported.